# Parse iOS push notifications stopped reaching the device even though the dashboard has records of them

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using Parse for push notifications and it has been working fine until a few days ago I stopped receiving notifications on two of my iOS devices (one running iOS 8.4 and the other 8.2). I can see notifications being sent in the Parse.com dash board. But I don't see them arriving at the notification center on the device. In XCode debugger, didn't see application.didReceiveRemoteNotification ever being called either. Strangely my iPhone running on iOS 7 still gets notifications running the same version of code as in iOS 8. So puzzled on what could be the problem.

Things have happened in the last few days:

1. upgraded one of the phones to iOS 8.4 but notifications doesn't work on 8.2 device either so the upgrade shouldn't be the cause
2. upgrade XCode to 6.4
3. 8.4 device was a new device (running on 8.3) I just added to the provisioning profile. It had some problem (that I can't remember the details of) when I clicked "fix it" button in XCode Identity settings when I connected the phone to XCode. Then some time later I noticed notifications weren't going through. I googled and found a suggestion to refresh my provisioning profile in Preferences->accounts->apple ID->view details->refresh button. Which seems have worked at the moment and I was getting notifications again. But it stopped working again one day later.
4. I tried to create a separate version of the app using a different bundle ID (with some suffix) and using the same facebook App ID by adding another URL Scheme in info.plist file. Couldn't get it to work as facebook login keeps bring me back to the old app so I un-did all the work. But I still see some new provisioning profiles with the new bundle id. So I deleted them in the apple developer site member center and refreshed profiles in XCode to pick up the changes.

That's all I can remember and I have no idea which action, if any of them, has caused the problem and how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify that push is enabled for iOS 8 in you app delegate?

```
  // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  }
  else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIUserNotificationTypeSound)];
  }
```

I would also start completely fresh and new with generation of all certificates, app, and provisioning profiles, and .p12 files - sounds like something is off but its a needle in a haystack. Do your due diligence and follow the process from A to Z:

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: yes I have the code above in place. It was working fine on both iOS 7 and 8 until it stopped working on 8.
I'll redo the certificates and see what happens.. thanks!

Comment: I redid the whole steps in the tutorial and it's working now it seems